# Nucleon-nucleon collision density

Tags: nuclear-physics, collision, density, heavy-ion

Can someone help me derive expression for nucleon-nucleon collision density as a function of transverse plane coordinates (ultra-relativistic heavy ion collisions) using Wood-Saxon nuclear densities( $1/(1 + e^{(r-c)/d})$) in Glauber model (c, d are constants)?

Comment: Can you expand on what resources you've looked at, what you've tried to do, and where you got stuck? Regardless of whether or not this is a homework question, following that advice as in our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) would go a long way toward making it a better question.

Comment: Glauber models are usual very straight ahead. You just treat the paths as classical and plow ahead with an integration of the collision probability. Simply enough even for a weak experimenter's brain like mine.